# Infinite calendar remove selection handler

Tags: reactjs

I use infinite Calendar
http://clauderic.github.io/react-infinite-calendar/#/events/on-select?_k=qe3pko

```
<InfiniteCalendar onSelect={function(date) {
      alert('You selected: ' + format(date, 'ddd, MMM Do YYYY'))
   }
/>
```

This code show the same alert if select or unselect date.
I need show differen alert, if I unslelect date.

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I guess there is no neat way to doing this by looking at the [source-code](https://github.com/clauderic/react-infinite-calendar/blob/d7a77fc1508cb4ded30e47baabb111a8d6461721/src/index.js#L15-L35)

Here is a way to do what you want

```
let oldDate = null;
function App() {
  return (
    <InfiniteCalendar
      interpolateSelection={(date) => {
        if (oldDate && oldDate.toString() === date.toString()) {
          oldDate = null;
          alert('You just de-selected: ' + format(date, 'ddd, MMM Do YYYY'))
          return 
          // or jump to today on deslect 
          // return Date.now();
        }
        oldDate = date;
        alert('You selected: ' + format(date, 'ddd, MMM Do YYYY'))
        return date;
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

you can do it even cleaner with react useState. I didn't use it cause it is not needed I guess, but you can add it if you want, just make sure to prevent extra re-renders.

if you want to use the following code for multiple components in the represented way, you must reset oldDate in components unmount.

you can also use useRef that both prevent re-renders and is reactive or the same with js itself

```
const oldDate = { current: null } // js version with nearly all same logic

// useRef version
function App() {
  const oldDate = useRef(null)
  return (
    <InfiniteCalendar
      interpolateSelection={(date) => {
        if (oldDate.current && oldDate.current.toString() === date.toString()) {
          oldDate.current = null;
          alert('You just de-selected: ' + format(date, 'ddd, MMM Do YYYY'))
          return 
        }
        oldDate.current = date;
        alert('You selected: ' + format(date, 'ddd, MMM Do YYYY'))
        return date;
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It almost worked, but if i select date, and them select another date - i get message 'You just de-selected: ', but my first changed date - is selected.

Comment: Is what i need post request on server after click date, and Delete request if unchecked date. Post request is sending Done, but delete request I can't do, because unselect event started post request again. 

Sorry for my english))

Its big problem - find good multiply data picker, which can get dates array, post dates and delete dates from server.å

This calendar can get and post, but delete request - its problem(

Comment: I fixed the problem you mentioned @kashmir1

Comment: The Material-UI date picker handles both localization and lots of other stuff itself :)

Comment: Big respect from me!

Comment: It really helped. I am happy that there are people like you. Thanks!